How add this lines?

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin {axis}[width=7cm,
 axis lines=center ,
 xmax=14,% xmin removed
 ymin=0,ymax=30,
 ymajorgrids=true,
 ylabel near ticks ,
 xlabel near ticks ,
 major grid style={thick},
 tick style={thick},
 axis line style={thick},
 xlabel= \textarabic{text},
 ylabel=\textarabic{text},
 title =\textarabic{text },
 xtickmin =6,
 %x t i c k = { 6 , 8 , . . . , 1 4 } ,
 ytick ={0,5,...,30} ,
 ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
 enlargelimits={ abs=5mm}]
 \addplot[ybar interval, fill =red!70]
 coordinates{(6,10)(8,30)(10,10)(12,20)
 (14,20)};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}


Can you please make your example compilable?
